# Can const member variable of class be initialized in a method instead of constructor?

Tags: c++, class, design-patterns, initialization, constants

I have a class and want to create a const int variable but the value for the variable is not available to me in constructor of the class.

In initialization method of the class i get the value. Can I assign it in that method?
 As I am assigning it only once (as const says) why it isn't working?

Code is as Following [Just a ProtoType] :

**File : A.h**

```
Class A
{
  private :
  const long int iConstValue;

  public :
  A();
  initClassA();
}
```

**File : A.cpp**

```
A::A()
{
 //CanNot initialize iConstValue (Don't have it)
}

A::initClassA(some params)
{
 // calculation according to params for iConstValue
 iConstValue = (some value)
}
```

This is not working. Somebody has any Solutions?

**NOTE :** I **Can not get value for iconstValue in constructor** by any way as there are some restriction. So Please don't suggest to do that.

Comment: "I am assigning it only once (as const says)" - const does not say you can assign it once. const says that you cannot assign it at all (but you can initialize it). Assignment and initialization are different things, and what you're attempting is assignment.

Comment: Why does your class need `iConstValue` to be `const`? Perhaps your design needs to be re-assessed?

Comment: The class design is flawed then. You *should* be able to get the value in the constructor, otherwise you have an object which isn’t initialised properly, and initialisation is the job of the constructor.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A small example:

```
class A
{
public:
  A():a(initial_value_of_a()) {}

private:
  const int a;
  int initial_value_of_a() { return 5; /* some computation here */ };
};
```

Answer (score 5):

`const` doesn't mean you can only assign it once, you can *never* assign to a const object.  A const variable is initialized once and its value cannot change.  So you initialize it in the constructor, when all members and bases are initialized, then you can't change it after that.

If you can't get the value on construction you could either make the variable non-const, so you modify it, or maybe you could delay construction until you have all the data, using a placeholder until you construct the real object.

Two-stage construction is a code smell, it's certainly incompatible with const members.

Comment: In my scenario class has a child which have to instantiate the class object on its construction. But child has a raw data (need to processed to get const value) So how do I delay the instantiation of parent class.

Comment: I don't understand that comment. What class object? What raw data? Can you change your question to make it clear what you mean? You need to change your design, why can't the member be non-const?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do that, because you cannot change the value of a const variable. by the time `initClassA` runs the const data member has already been initialized (to some garbage value in this case). So you can only really initialize the data member to some value in the constructor initializer list.

If you want to set the variable only once, then you can make is non-const, and add a guard so it can only be set once. This isn't pretty but it would work:

```
class A
{
  private :
   long int iValue;
   bool isInitialised;

  public :
  A() : iValue(0), isInitialized(false);
  bool initClassA() {
    if (isInitialized) return false;
    iValue = something:
    isInitialized = true;
    return true;
  }
}
```

But it isn't good practice to have objects that can be initialized or not. Objects should be in a coherent state when constructed, and clients should not have to check whether these objects are initialized.

Comment: So what is the alternative to this, I want a long int in a class which not supposed to be changed once value is assigned.

Comment: @AnwarShaikh the alternative is to give only const access to the variable.

Comment: I would suggest throwing an exception,maybe derived from std::logic_error, if the init function is called twice. If the program does that it's broken.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you can do, is change for a int pointer, receive this pointer in your constructor, and change the pointer where you want :P

But it will not be the same functionnality cause it will be the pointer which is const and not anymore the value :/

Answer (score 0):

I think I need to change the design and I should calculate the (or get) the const variables value at constructor any how. As there is no way I can set it's value later.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful.